# Android Studio, Xcode, Cocopods

Tags: xcode, android-studio, flutter, cocoapods

Im new to app development so forgive me if this is a trivial question.

I am trying to build a Flutter application in Android Studios using Xcode simulator as my IOS emulator. When I run main.dart on  my application i get the following error in Android Studios console. [error message in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyFV8.png)

I have tried a variety of fixes but am unsure of any answers.

Delete Podfile and run `pod init` then `pod install`

If anyone could shed some light on what is actually wrong with my issue that would be terrific.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem is with **deployment target**. You can change this as following:

[image: Change deployment target]

Change it to 8.0. If 8.0 is not available then try with other iPhone simulator with a higher iOS version.

And please read your error fully, it mentions about the deployment target.

Comment: XCode, select your project from left panel. and then make change to Deployment Target

Answer (score 0):

Add/ change this at the bottom of your Podfile (located at ios/Podfile)

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '8.0'
    end
  end
end
```